# Regex multiple orders of named groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a set of patterns that occur in multiple orders. I'd like to refer to each pattern with a name in order to sort them and extract their information. The below code doesn't work because a named group may only be defined once and putting a group in more than one operand of the | operator is interpreted as a redefinition.

```
a = r'(?P<A>AAA)'
b = r'(?P<B>BBB)'
c = r'(?P<C>CCC)'
d = r'(?P<D>DDD)'
x = r'(?P<X>XXX)'

cases = '|'.join([fr'{a}{b}{c}',
                  fr'{b}{c}{x}',
                  fr'{b}{a}{x}',
                  fr'{x}{d}{a}',
                  ...])

pattern = fr'({cases})'

result = [(x.group('A'),
           x.group('B'),
           x.group('C'),
           x.group('D'),
           x.group('x'))
          for x in re.finditer(pattern, long_string)]
```

Is there a way to put a group with the same name in different parts of the | operator?

Comment: Yes, if you use PyPi regex module. `re` does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined your named group, you have to use named back references.

For exemple, to refer to the A group :

```
(?P=A)
```

[image]

See the documentation : https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html?wlr=1

Comment: This only works, if the second occurrence is the same string, but not if it's the same regex pattern.
(?P<A>[0-9]+)(?P<B>BBB)(?P<C>CCC)?(?P=A) does not match P123BBBCCC789
I'd like both 123 and 789 to be extracted by the same identifier.

Comment: So, I think you should rethink your pattern. How do you know what to extract ? have you output examples ?